# create a report in mysql and store it in a log file, using triggers, and then analyze the log

Tags: mysql, logfile

I need to create a report on a monthly or daily basis (whichever is more easy) for a specific table containing the number of records that got updated, inserted or deleted in this period.

The table contains a column named updatedate and another named deleted where the value 0 means it is not deleted, and the value 1 means it was deleted. Finally, there is the primary key column, named id.

The following code returns the records deleted for a certain period of time:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
    WHERE updateDate >='2019-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND updateDate <'2019-02-13 00:00:00' AND deleted = '1'
```

Which queries should one run also, in order to get a report of the newly created - inserted records?

I guess one should also somehow count the number of ids that exist in the starting date, and then the number of ids that exist in the end date, and then do the subtraction in order to get the number of the newly inserted records? Ideally i would like to have these reports in separate files

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  updatedate DATETIME,
  product_id INT,
  deleted INT,
  customer_id INT
);
INSERT INTO orders (updatedate, product_id, deleted, customer_id)
  VALUES
  ('2019-08-15 12:20:20', '1', '0', '123'),
  ('2019-08-15 12:20:20', '2', '0', '123'),
  ('2019-08-17 16:43:09', '4', '0', '456'),
  ('2019-08-18 09:21:43', '8', '0', '789'),
  ('2019-08-18 14:23:11', '12', '0', '123'),
  ('2019-08-21 08:34:21', '19', '0', '456');
```

example output of the updated records: (assuming the record ids are not new for the month under question)

date total_updates

```
2009-08-15  2
2009-08-17  1
2009-08-18  2
2009-08-21  1
```

Same table is needed for the records deleted and created in a month basis. This must be based only on the record ids that differ from the previous month.

ie if id 88 was not in the table orders in the last day of the previous month, then this is a newly inserted record. If id 13 was in the table orders in the last previous month's last day, and in this month's last day it is not, then this is a deleted record (something which may also occur from the column deleted combined with the updatedate column)

So this report could look like:

January:

```
123 records inserted
456 records deleted
```

EDIT: as was kindly spotted, in the comments, this approach is not totally safe, since we may loose some actions. Could you please elaborate on the solution
"A safer approach is to capture all events to a log using triggers and analyse that" given the fact that any change to the current scheme is not allowed, but we can store data in a new external scheme.

Comment: You could have matched your inserts to the table definition...

Comment: unfortunately this is not going to change soon, the definition of the table i mean, thus i need a solution with the above data

Comment: I get that but how do you INSERT INTO orders (order_date, product_id, customer_id) when order_date does not exist in your table and how do you get away with not providing deleted in your insert list?

Comment: Given what I think your design is it's not safe (in my view). for example if you have id 88 added in month 1 then updated in month 2 in month 2 you have lost the fact that id  88 was created in month 1 (updateddate is month 2) - so you cannot retrospectively find inserts for month 1. Similarly if 88 was added,updated and deleted in month 1 then you have lost the fact that an update occurred . A safer approach is to capture all events to a log using triggers and analyse that.

Comment: since i did not have a column named inserted date, or deleted date, i thought an approximate solution would do. But your approach seems very elegant, if you could provide a working example?